# Flash Loan Arbitrage Bot

Tags: solidity, flash-loans, arbitrage

I'm design an Arbitrage bot, and I wanted it to grab the funds from a flash loan.

How would you implement this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

in general, your app needs to have two parts:

1. A program that finds arbitrage opportunities.
2. A program that gets the flashloan and uses it to act on the arbitrage opportunity.

This tutorial shows you how to deploy a smart contract to receive and use a flashloan from Aave V3.

- [Aave V3 flash loan with Hardhat](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/avalanche-tutorial-aavev3-flash-loans-with-hardhat)

This one is a step-by-step guide on how to develop and deploy the smart contract using HardHat. It is based on the Avalanche Fuji testnet, but it can be configured for any chain supported by Aave.